# Instantiate javax.xml.rpc.Service

Tags: java, spring-boot, javax.xml

I have an issue with this code:

```
ScheduleWSFacadeBindingStub scheduleFacadeBindingStub = new ScheduleWSFacadeBindingStub(service);
scheduleVO = scheduleFacadeBindingStub.generateScheduleV2(schedule);
```

Service is `javax.xml.rpc.Service`. Initially I tried autowiring it into the class with:

```
@Autowired Service service;
```

When I ran the application I got:

> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field service in path.to.my.application.ScheduleClient required a bean of type 'javax.xml.rpc.Service' that could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.xml.rpc.Service' in your configuration.

I'm now trying to instantiate it directly but I think it needs to use a wsdl file which is in my project root. Is this correct and if so how do I instantiate it?